# how do I center two rows inside a column using css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

hello sorry if this is a basic question, I have 3 columns made using bootstrap, and the image below is the 2nd column I'm trying to center these two rows to the middle of the div (or 2nd col) or make the height of the 2nd column responsive, how can I do this with CSS?

[image]

Comment: look up flex, a flex container can center it's contents

Comment: Here are all sorts of examples using Flex. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: There's examples of this in [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/) for alignment.

Comment: share your html also, eventually make a snippet, so you can demonstrate your issue. A screenshot doesn't tell the html and class you used. `d-flex flex-column align-items-center`are classes availaible in bootstrap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.

```css
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
  width: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
  background: grey;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 60%;
  height: 3rem;
  background: white;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```